# Setting Image Close to TextView - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am sure this is very basic but i don't get why my image(icon) wouldn't show up on the left of my text. I want to have something like this 
`(icon) Text`. This is what i have tried using left drawables but it won't work for me.

**listItem.axml**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="63"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

**Activity**

```
     textIcon = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
                textIcon.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.Icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

**Adapter and Holder**

```
  public class Fragment : SupportFragment

        {
            public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Create your fragment here
            }


            public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment, container, false) as RecyclerView;

                SetUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);

                return recyclerView;
            }

            private void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
            {
                recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));

                var Adapter = new EventAdapter(Collection.GetData());

                recyclerView.SetAdapter(Adapter);



            }

            public class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
            {

                private JavaList<MyData> AllData;

                public EventAdapter(JavaList<MyData> AllData)
                {
                    this.AllData = AllData;

                }


                public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                    MyHolder hold = holder as MyHolder;
                    hold.Name.Text = AllData[position].Name;



   }


                public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItem, parent, false);
                    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(v);

                    return holder;
                }

                public override int ItemCount
                {

                    get { return AllData.Size(); }

                }

            }
        }




    public class MyHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView Name;


        public EventHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            Name = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);




        }


    }
```

Comment: list item is displaying a text on a recyclerView on the Activity page. So i am trying to bind the icon the to textView1. The Activity page displays the list item : )

Comment: did you try notifydatasetchanged() after updating icon?

Comment: I didn't not try that. How do i update icon with that function ?

Comment: please show me more code or try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
this is function is for updating view chnages in adapter inside list view

Comment: @JaydeepPatel i have added my adapter and holder

Comment: just add Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setting up textview icon.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel in my activity class? My adpater is set up in the fragement class

Comment: then update textviwe icon in fragment

Comment: Thanks.. that worked!!

Comment: always welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put notifydatasetchnaged after view update inside fragment.

```
  textIcon = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
                textIcon.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.Icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

and then notify to adapter

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```